# python await asyncio.sleep() in while true blocks

Tags: python, while-loop, python-asyncio, git-bash

I have the following python program testing `asyncio`:

```
import asyncio

async def task():
    print("doing task")
    while True:
        print("while true looping")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        print("starting loop")
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
                task()
            )
        )
    finally:
        loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am expecting outputs like the following:

```
starting loop
doing task
while true loop
while true loop
...("while true loop every" 2 seconds)
```

or even:

```
doing task
while true loop
starting loop
while true loop
...("while true loop every" 2 seconds)
```

But instead, the program hangs and outputs nothing. I guess I have misunderstood the way `asyncio` handles the loop or `asyncio.sleep()` works, but I thought `await asyncio.sleep()` passes the control back to the caller thus the other `print()` can execute.

What have I got wrong here and how can I get the desired outputs?

EDIT: this seemed to be a problem specific to Git-Bash on Windows, when I tried the program with windows command prompt and powershell, the desired output were shown.